# How to wrap a Func<T1...Tn> with unknown number and type of parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class Function {
    public int argc;        //number of arguments of the function
    public float[] argv;
    public Func<float> f;   //attribute to store a function (e.g. Sin(x) or Pow(a, b))
}
```

I want to create instances of `Function` that hold different functions, like `Sin(x)` or `Pow(a, b)`, but I don't know how to bind an existing function (with any number of arguments) to a `Func`. Obviously its declaration would not always be `Func<float>` but `Func<float, float>`, `Func<float, float, float>`, etc.

I've looked for `Func`, `delegate`, `Action` but still didn't figure out how to have this "function capsule" that can hold and execute functions with different number of arguments. For simplicity I consider the only input and output type is `float`.

I'm thinking about using something like `Func<List<float>>` but I want to know if there is a better option.

Comment: Well, `Func<float>` just returns a float. It looks like your `Function` instance would store a list of arguments.. so why not just use a parameterless delegate (which you have; `Func<float>`) and use `argv` in its closure?

Comment: i.e.: `this.f = delegate() { return Math.Pow(this.argv[0], this.argv[1])};`

Comment: It gives me an error `this.f is a type but it's used as a variable`. I declared `f` as `public delegate float f();` and in the constructor, I wrote the same code you sent.

Comment: Sorry, try this. I missed a semi-colon and a cast: `this.f = delegate() { return (float)Math.Pow(this.argv[0], this.argv[1]);};` ([REPL](https://repl.it/@piboistudios/Invokable))

Comment: Leave `f` as `public Func<float> f;`

Comment: This is surely a wierd syntax but it might to the trick, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, delegates can get very verbose in C# but they're very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to suggest an answer that fits more accurately the scenario described by the OP. The key is in the usage of `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` which lets you pass an indefinite number of arguments to a delegate.

```cs
public class Function<TReturn> {
    private readonly object[] _argv;

    private readonly Delegate _func;

    public Function(Delegate func, params object[] args) {
        _func = func;
        _argv = args;
    }

    public TReturn Run() {
        object v = _func.DynamicInvoke(_argv);
        return (TReturn)v;
    }
}
```

And its usage lets you decide dynamically the number of arguments you wish to pass:

```cs
var s = new Function<double>((Func<double, double>)(x => Math.Sin(x)), 1 );
Console.WriteLine(s.Run()); // prints 0.8414709848078965

var p = new Function<double>((Func<double, double, double>)((a, b) => Math.Pow(a, b)), 2, 3);
Console.WriteLine(p.Run()); // prints 8

var d = new Function<string>((Func<string, double, string>)((a, b) => a + b.ToString()), "hello, ", 42);
Console.WriteLine(p.Run()); // prints "hello, 42"
```

Note that type checking is only performed at run-time when calling `Function.Run()` and not when constructing the `Function` object because of its dynamic nature. If you know for sure that all passed arguments will always be of the same type, you could enforce that statically by adding a `TArg` generic type.

Comment: This is indeed a great solution. Do you think I could extend this to accept any type of argument instead of only doubles?

Comment: I edited my post to allow any type or arguments, and by adding a TReturn genericity for `Function` to specify the return type. You could leave it to `object` but this way you have a minimum amount of type-checking.